# expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int' in C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, singly-linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I have a code like this to reverse a singly linked list by using a stack. But when I call the pushStack function, I get an error like this; "expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int'"

```
{
    // store Node addresses in stack
    struct STACK *stk;
    struct Student* ptr = head;
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        pushStack(stk, ptr->studentnumber);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
 
    // print data from stack
    while (!emptyStack(stk)) {
        printf(stk->top);
        pop(); // pop after print
    }
}
```

This is my pushStack function;

```
bool pushStack (struct STACK* stack, int *dataInPtr)
{
//  Local Definitions 
    STACK_NODE* newPtr;

//  Statements 
    newPtr = (STACK_NODE* ) malloc(sizeof(STACK_NODE));
    if (!newPtr)
        return false;

    newPtr->dataPtr = dataInPtr; 

    newPtr->link    = stack->top; 
    stack->top      = newPtr; 

    (stack->count)++; 
    return true;
}   // pushStack
```

I defined studentnumber as an integer in the struct. As far as I understand I need to convert the list into multilinked-list, so in this way, I can pass studentnumber as a pointer but I want it to remain as a singly linked list. What can I do, if anyone has an opinion, I would really aprecciated it.

Comment: At least `printf(stk->top);` looks definitely wrong.

Comment: Use `bool pushStack (struct STACK* stack, int data)`. I guess `studentnumber`, which you pass as second argument is of type `int` not `int *`.
Besides that your method is quite inefficient. All you need to do is process the list from the start, reverse the next pointer (you always need to remember one pointer) and at last point the head to the former last element.

Comment: When I pass an integer as a parameter to pushStack function, I get this error "assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast". Because I define my stack like this: `typedef struct node2 
    {
     void* dataPtr;
     struct node2* link;
    } STACK_NODE; ` I get an error for this `newPtr->dataPtr = dataInPtr; ` but in order to use stack for also storing strings, I should keep dataPtr as a void pointer, right? @pqans

Comment: I understand, but first keep it simple. When that works make your list generic. Please provide the complete code including datatype definitions, next time.

Comment: Does your assignment require the use of the stack for this problem? You should be able to walk a list and reverse it in a single in-situ pass. Please read [ask] and post an [mcve].

Comment: Yes, I need to use stack to reverse the list. I will read the links, thanks @jwdonahue

Comment: If you don't need both a stack of integers and a stack of strings in the same program, don't use a void pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error that you are getting is because when you call the `pushStack` function like this: `pushStack(stk, ptr->studentnumber)`, the second argument, as you specified, is an `int`, but you need `int *`. So it would have to be something like this: `pushStack(stk, &ptr->studentnumber)`. This only concerns the error you are getting, I am not sure that the code that you provided does what is intended to do.